# Switching from UITableViewController, to new UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I know that to go from one TableViewController, to a new TabBarController, you can use a "segue" from the Storyboard and add the following code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    ViewController *vc = (ViewController *) [[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

But my problem is that I cannot use either "segue", storyboard or method -prepareForSegue:sender:

My question is, how can I pass from TableViewController, to my new TabBarController by code?

**RESOLVED**

I used the method -performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

In the storyboard I control-drag from my source viewController (Grid view) to my destination TabBarController.

In -didSelectRow method of my Grid I call -performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: thats trigger -prepareForSegue:sender: and so to implement the code necessary to complete the process

Comment: Why can't you use a segue or the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method?

Comment: Because I use a custom cell to display a Gridview (with two columns). And its design is new .xib rather than in the storyboard. I have to push the new UITabBarController  on the method - tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: